# Is there a theorical expression size limit for "or" operator on Regex.Replace

Tags: .net, regex, limit

Is there a theorical expression size limit for "or" operator on Regex.Replace
such as  Regex.Replace("abc","(a|c|d|e...continue say 500000 elements here)","zzz") ?

Any stackoverflowException on .NET's implementation ?

Thanks

Comment: If you plan on having a 500000 element long regex pattern, you may want to rethink your solutions architecture. ;)

Comment: Do you mean theoretical limit or do you mean is there a practical limit?

Comment: @Chris both. I am also interested in the situation where it goes compiled ie. new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no theoretical limit, though each regular expression engine will have its own implementation limits. In this case, since you are using .NET the limit is due to the amount of memory the .NET runtime can use.

A regular expression with one million alernations works fine for me:

```
string input = "a<142>c";
var options = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(x => "<" + x + ">");
string pattern = string.Join("|", options);
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "zzz");
```

Result:

```
azzzc
```

It's very slow though. Increasing the number of options to 10 million gives me an `OutOfMemoryException`.

You probably would benefit from looking at another approach.

Comment: new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled); seems to be OK too, and there is no ram spike until .Replace is taken place. Perhaps it is the backtracking that uses massive ram. thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

The way regular expressions work mean that the memory requirements and performance for a simple `a|b|c.....|x|y|z` expression as described are not too bad, even for a very large number of variants.

However, if your expression is even slightly more complex than that, you could cause the expression to lose performance exponentially, as well as massively growing its memory footprint, as an large number of `or` options like this can cause it to have to do massive amounts of backtracking if other parts of the expression don't match immediately.

You may therefore want to excersise caution either doing this sort of thing. Even if it works now, it would only take a small and relatively innocent change to make the whole thing come to a grinding halt.

Comment: Edited to change "backreferencing" to "backtracking", which I think is what you meant. Backreferences are something else. Feel free to roll back if you were actually talking about them, though.