# How can I achieve password regex?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, c#-4.0, password-protection

I want validation using regex pattern in my project.

Following are  description of regex pattern:

1. Must be at least 8 characters in length.
2. Must contain at least 1 UPPER CASE  character.
3. Must contain at least 1 lower case character.
4. Must contain at least 1 number.
5. May contain these characters:

> " < > $ ~ ' ` ! @ # % ^ & * ( ) - + { } [ ] = : , . ? / | \

6. Must not use repeating characters. (aa, 11, etc.)
7. Must not use more than 3 sequential characters. (abcd, wxyz, 1234, etc.)

Comment: Might I suggest that your last conditions (f,g) don't actually make your password stronger - they limit the number of passwords one can choose from. On the other hand a lower limit of just eight is laughable. And why do you want to use Regex? These "repeating strings" things are better solved with other tools. Is this "exercise" or "real work"? In the latter case, telling us what tool you want to use but not providing any attempt yourself goes against the spirit of SO questions, which are meant to demonstrate effort.

Comment: Would you consider `ABCd` to violate rule (g)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$
```

**PS:** It meets all conditions and I didn't include characters mentioned in `section e.` since you wrote `May contain` and dot will allow all of those.

**UPDATE: As per edited question:** Use this regex to meet conditions `(a) - (f)`

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?:(?!.*?(.)\1).){8,}$
```

**I would highly recomment not using regex for meeting condition `(g)` since it will be an awfully long regex.**

Comment: Need condition (e) explicitly instead of just `.{8}`

Comment: And "at least 8:' `{8,}`

Comment: @Floris: Please read my explanation about `(e)` in question and thanks I made it `{8,}` in my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work, it requires 8 characters at least AFTER the final condition is met.

Comment: @TimEbenezer: That's not correct. It will require 8 character from start. All conditions are lookahead, they don't match.

Comment: I think it needs `[]a-zA-Z0-9<>$~'``!@#%^&*()-+{}[]{8,}` - tricky syntax on special character `]` not sure putting it first is enough...

Comment: @ManishSharma: Please, **you shouldn't change very nature of your question**. Conditions `f) and g)` can be done by regex but that will make regex pretty complicated.

Comment: @anubhava i konow that but i forgot to put this condition.

Comment: After reading `(g)` again, no regex cannot enforce sequential check.

Comment: "No regex can"? `(ABCD)|(BCDE)|(CDEF)`.... Sorry I could not help myself. It would be a long one. And horribly inefficient. But it exists.

Comment: @Floris: lol :) and when you add lowercase letters and digits also on top of that it will sure exhaust max lenght that regex engine can take.

Comment: @anubhava I think it would be fine - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7529031/1967396 . I might just generate it for kicks...

Comment: You are still not addressing condition (e), which does not allow for `\€£¥` to name but four characters I see right on my keyboard...